# Dynamic Height Modal with Scrolling Panels

Tags: html, css, scroll, height, responsive

I am trying to create a modal. I want this modal to use all but 96px of the view-height (48px padding on the top and bottom).

The catch is that modal needs to have two scroll-able panels within it. This is the part that is giving me trouble. Because the modal height is dynamic, it is difficult to give the scrolling areas a height that is also responsive and allows all of the panel's content to be scroll-able.

Is there a way to give the scrolling panels a responsive height that will allow all of the panel content to be viewed, regardless of the view-height?

Example: https://codepen.io/dean-o-saur/pen/OzjQvQ

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scroll Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0b7dc70bea.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modalContainer">
        <div class="modalContent">
            <div class="titleBar">
                <p>Title</p>
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="modalBody">
                <div class="MBLeft">
                    <div class="sectionTop">
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sectionBottom">
                        <p><strong>TOP</strong></p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p><strong>BOTTOM</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="MBRight">
                    <div class="rightContent">
                        <p><strong>TOP</strong></p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p><strong>BOTTOM</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #7F7F7F;
}

.modalContainer{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 48px;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
    height: calc(100vh - 96px);
    max-height: calc(100vh - 96px);
}

.modalContent{
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 950px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid rgb(201, 201, 209);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.titleBar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 22px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 0 20px 0 17px;
}

.titleBar i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  align-self: center;
}

.modalBody{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 340px auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 18.5%);
}

.modalBody p{
  margin:3px;
}

.modalBody p:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.modalBody p:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.MBLeft{
  border-right: 2px solid gray;
  height: 100%;
}

.MBRight{
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.rightContent{
  padding: 23px 20px 20px;
}

.sectionTop {
  padding: 23px 20px 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}

.sectionBottom{
  padding: 23px 20px 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 55vh;
}

.sectionBottom p{
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I played around with this and came to a solution that I am happy with. I updated the CodePen linked to in the question.

Looks like the panels I was trying to get to scroll needed a height. For some reason I was working under the assumption that the panel's parent divs were the ones that needed the height.

Also formatting the height style like this helped:

```
height: calc(100vh - 385px);
```

I had to play with the 385 pixel value to get it to work correctly, but this seemed to do the trick.